# Drawing 3D sprites with opengl

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d

Lets say I want to draw a simple 3D hero with OpenGL. Here are my questions:

1. Is there a way to export 3D drawings from Adobe Illustrator CS5.1?
2. Are there any other programs, where you can draw 3D objects and export them for android development?
3. How do the professionals draw their 3D objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here goes it all again:

1. OpenGL is not a rendering toolkit, scenegraph or whatever. It is a glorified triangle rasterizer. OpenGL knows nothing about fancy file formats for 3D objects and never will (but you can write your own loader of any format).
2. Android is not different in any respect here. It depends on which formats are supported and usually you can add loaders for different file-formats yourself.
3. Depends. Maya and Blender are two I know of.

Comment: so where can i start, and what will i need?

Comment: @Liukas Either you go for raw OpenGL and write some of the infrastructure yourself or look for some framework that does some of work for you. Despite all that, you should learn some basic 3D programming concepts first.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to export 3D drawings from adobe illustrator CS5.1?

No, Illustrator is a 2D drawing program.

> Are there any other programs, where you can draw 3D objects …

Blender, Maya, 3D Studio Max, XSI Softimage, Milkshape3D, Wings, SketchUp, and some more.

> and export them for android development.

There's nothing specific to android. You save the 3D model in some file format you can read. Then your program reads the objects from the files with the known file format, put the data into their data structures and use those to command whatever 3D API is used. Like OpenGL.

OpenGL just sees a bunch of commands to draw triangles, lines and points to the scene.

> How do the proffesionals draw they're 3D objects?

They don't draw them, they model them in a 3D modelling program. I named you a few.

Comment: PS you have enough rep to fix the question instead of complaining about the spelling

Comment: @BenVoigt: Lets just hope I never run into that guy: http://www.smbc-comics.com/index.php?db=comics&id=2478#comic